# Not able to find validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to skip a validation rule in production for deployment and I am not able to find the validation rule for the object. I searched in workbench with no luck.

I tried adding 'ValidationRule' in package.xml with the hope of retrieving but couldn't in Mavensmate.

Comment: What details do you know about the validation rule in question? I.e. do you know its name and ID? How do you intend to skip the rule in deployment?

Comment: How you are gonna skip in deployment.And while deployment you will receive  validation error message.Search with in validation rules with this subject.

Comment: I only have the validation message that is shown on validation failure. I tried to search for it in Mavensmate/workbench without luck :( .I want to deactivate it so that I can pass the validation, not a good practice, I know, but the need of the hour.